# GeoServer unable to read from foreign tables?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, geometry, fdw

When I add a layer in GeoServer that is a foreign table in my database, I get an error of:

> Failed to load attribute list, internal error is: Schema 'table' does
> not exist .

When I add that same layer as a regular table or a materialized view, GeoServer is able to read from the table properly.

Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the issue by creating a regular view.

```sql
CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT * FROM my_foreign_table
```

Maybe you will need to explicit geometry type and crs in the view definition ( ex : `geom::geometry(Point,4326)` )

Comment: I'm trying to avoid creating a view, as I have 50+ foreign tables. Does Geoserver support reading foreign tables? I couldn't find any documentation regarding foreign tables? Is creating a view the only way around this problem?